# unable to change width of image with bootstrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm working on Carousel image slider with bootstrap. I'm unable to change the height of the image. If I try to change the height it's effecting for both height and width both. But I need to modify only width.

My code is like below :

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/
    bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js">
  </script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js">
  </script>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="container">
    <h2>Carousel Example</h2>
    <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
      <!-- Indicators -->
      <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
      </ol>

      <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
      <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="item active">
          <img src="la.jpg" alt="Los Angeles" style="width:10%; height:50%">
        </div>

        <div class="item">
          <img src="chicago.jpg" alt="Chicago" style="width:20%; height:50%">
        </div>

        <div class="item">
          <img src="ny.jpg" alt="New york" style="width:30%; height:50%">
        </div>
      </div>

      <!-- Left and right controls -->
      <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
      </a>
      <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Could you please share your css code?

Comment: all I had provided through CDN's.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
.carousel-inner .item img{
   max-width: none;
   width: your-width:
   height: your-height;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Percent height is tricky because it depends on parent height, which in this case there are none, resulting in that your image height means nothing.

You can set a fixed height on the parent (not using percent) Or you can set a percent-based height on the parent, but then IT'S parent needs a fixed height. And the same is true all the way up to the html-element, which you can set a 100% height on and the browser will respect it, but it's a really ugly way of doing things.

There are ways around this of course. It also seems like you don't mind if the image is stretched, so that is another assumption I'm making. With that said I think the easiest option here is to use vw/vh units. They work almost as percent, but `vw/vh` is based on viewport width or height and not parent height. Thus:

```
<img src="la.jpg" alt="Los Angeles" style="width:30vw; height:10vw">
```

Of course, if you don't know the exact ratios, the image will be stretched. (use `height: auto` for a non-stretched image).

[Here is various browser support for the vh/vw units.](http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units)

If you want the image to appear cropped, you are better off using css `background-image` and `background-size` instead of a `img` element. (Your intentions are not obvious from your question.)